# Dell M5010 wireless not working after upgrade

Tags: wireless

I dual installed ubuntu on my Dell M5010 Windows 7 laptop. Everything was fine until I installed the update. At that point my wireless would not connect. Can you please help me?

Comment: Not working as in? You are not able to connect to wireless networks? Can you be a bit more Specific

Comment: It shows no wireless connections to connect to

Comment: Still works on Windows boot though.

Comment: Try running `rfkill unblock all`

Restart your network manager with this command:

`sudo service network-manager restart`

Comment: That did not work. But thank you for trying.

Comment: @Mukund I got it working but I had to reinstall the update. Don't know really how I fixed it. But thank you for the advice.